Can I change the default hash function?
I is possible to change the default hash function that lua (or luajit) uses for the HashTable part of a talbe ?
I want to speedup table access in pure Lua.
I saw that:

The Default hash function for lua is not exposed
There is no metatable value for the hashing (not mentionned in the documentation, and by any chance __hash does not work)


Not possible unless you're willing to modify the Lua implementation. Note also that a Lua-side hash function would be extremely likely to be slower than whatever is currently implemented in C, especially on PUC Lua.
